# How to check if a string represents a floating-point number?

Tags: rust

Is there a way in Rust to check if a string contains a floating-point number without resorting to regexes?

Something giving similar result as this (used regex: https://regex101.com/r/pV6wJ6/2)

```
re = Regex::new(r#"^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$"#).unwrap()
assert_eq!(is_number(some_string), re.is_match(some_string))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You didn't give any examples, so I'll use `"1.23"` and `"bob"`.

Just try to parse it:

```
fn main() {
    let num = "1.23".parse::<f64>();
    match num {
        Ok(val) => println!("Yes, it was a number ({})", val),
        Err(why) => println!("Doesn't look like a number ({})", why),
    }
}
```

[`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) can return any type that implements the [`FromStr` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). In this case, `f64` defines [`ParseFloatError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.ParseFloatError.html) as the errors possible when converting a string to a floating point number.

If you *just* care if it is a number or not, you can use [`is_ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.is_ok):

```
fn main() {
    let is_num = "1.23".parse::<f64>().is_ok();
    println!("Is a number: {}", is_num);
}
```